# which is the best way to store and relogin with username and password?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

Hello i have an application which all activities can be reached after login (like facebook)
I want to write work flow

Status: launch application first time
Login screen-> get username and pass -> check from db -> if true save username and pass to sharedpref -> mainactivity

Status: closed application without logout and restart
Login screen-> get username and pass FROM SHAREDPREFERENCES -> check from db -> if true save username and pass to sharedpref -> mainactivity

I want to jumpover check from db step
Is it safe to set application "if username and password are in sharedprefereces directly show mainactivity because you have also checked and saved to sharedpref"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to account for the account being deleted or the password being changed, so no that will not work.

The best way to save a user's credentials is to implement a token system like [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) on your server, and store the token instead of the username/password.

If you can't modify the server, then your best bet is to store username and an encrypted password, and authenticate with the server every time the user opens the app.